# Cloudfoundry, Default protocol

Tags: tomcat, comet, cloud-foundry

I have a web application deployed in cloudfoundry, and now i want to change the default protocol used by tomcat by editing servelt.xml in my cloud deployment.

Does cloudfoundry allow you to alter servlet.xml ?

```
    <!--
<Connector port="8080" protocol="**HTTP/1.1**" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
           -->

<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080"   
   protocol="**org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol**" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure Tomcat with HTTPS, you cannot.  All SSL is terminated at the router, and internal traffic is HTTP.

You can make other changes to yourTomcat configuration by using Standalone Application:
http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/06/18/deploying-tomcat-7-using-the-standalone-framework/

Comment: While staging the application, i am facing an error " failed: web.xml not found" and In the options given to choose the application type while pushing,  i get "JavaWeb" but not "Java" in the options.  Not sure what i am missing...

Comment: how are you pushing the application - using the Eclipse plugin, or via vmc? what version of vmc/plugin do you have? you may need to update to the latest.

Comment: hi Adi with the latest version of the vmc i have been able to deploy the the tomcat. Thanks a ton for the help.